# How to display the label from models.TextChoices in the template?

Tags: python, django, django-models

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) says that one can use `.label`, but it does not work in the template.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    class ModelChoices(models.TextChoices):
        ENUM = 'VALUE', 'Label'
    model_choice = models.CharField(choices=ModelChoices.choices)
```

In the template `object.model_choice` displays the value (`'VALUE'`).

`object.model_choice.label` displays nothing.

How is it possible to get the label (`'Label'`) in the template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use `get_{field_name}_display`

###### Python

```py
modelObj.get_model_choice_display()
```

###### Template

```html
{{modelObj.get_model_choice_display}}
```